Is there any way to deliver each rendered item as an array of strings to the items_list component?
Latest Drupal 10, SDC (single directory components) and SDC Display are enabled.
Assuming I have 2 components: items_list and item, fieds don't matter.
For the rendering complexity purpose, let's say those are paragraph type entities.
I render an item paragraph type with sdc_display, I choose my component, match the props/slots, so far so good.
Now inside items_list I would like to iterate over each rendered item separately with:
{% for item in items % }...{{item}}...{% endfor %} 

Let's say I want to add a wrapper around each item, note: wrapper inside the item template is not a proper solution.
SDC Display does not allow me to do that, the only setting it has is a separator (space, comma, "|" or whatever), but the content is always delivered to the items_list component as a joined string (with separator), not as renderable objects or as an array of the children (which in my case would be an array of strings, 1 item per array item).
What I got when I try to deliver the multivalue field to the component expecting either object or array is:

Drupal\Core\Render\Component\Exception\InvalidComponentException: [items] String value found, but an object is required in Drupal\Core\Theme\Component\ComponentValidator->validateProps() (line 203 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/Component/ComponentValidator.php).

Obviously, when I change component's prop type to string, it works, but I can not iterate through the items, because it's a single string of joined items.
Aside from having a custom template for the items_list paragraph, which would be a proxy, and hardcoding rendering each item for the second time inside the items_list template, is there any way to deliver each rendered item as an array of strings to the items_list component?

I don't get this: note: wrapper inside the item template is not a proper solution.. Because that's exactly what could solve your problem, no? A specific field template. You can also add more template suggestions if they don't exist yet.

Each item renders with its own layout, but it's items_list who decides the overall layout for each item based on different conditions [e.g. add grid/flex/gap classes from tailwind etc]. Having different paragraph types or view modes per item_list view mode for the item just for the sake of the wrapper is an overkill, if I can just render an item once and then deal with the layout on the items_list level.
That was just one of use-case examples, the general problem is sending multivalue field values to the components as arrays.
